# В sql запросе не подставляються строки но числа подставляються, не могу понять почему не работает, уже все перепробовал

Tags: php, sql, pdo

```
$page  = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$limit = 3;
$offset = $limit * ($page - 1);
$sort_column = "tasks.id";
$sql = ('SELECT tasks.id, tasks.task_text, tasks.status, names.name, emails.email FROM tasks INNER JOIN names ON tasks.id_name = names.id INNER JOIN emails ON tasks.id_email = emails.id ORDER BY :column DESC LIMIT :lim OFFSET :off');
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindValue(':column', $sort_column, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':lim', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindValue(':off', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: Что вас заставляет думать, что не подставляется? Каков результат операции?

Comment: Название колонок (как и таблиц) не получится вставить через плейсхолдеры.

Comment: Хочу через плейсхолдер ":column" вставить название столба, чтобы по это столбцу отсортировать, после вставки вывод данных должен измениться, но переменная просто не подставляется,никаких ошибок  не выводиться, но другие переменные подставляются.

Comment: Наверное, так и надо писать тгда - не вставляется **имя колонки**, а не "строка"?

Comment: Я заметил одну закономерность, если убрать числовые значения, то строка подставляется, но когда я подставляю вместе с числом, строка игнорируеться,  поэтому я подумал что это из-за разных типов. Так должно быть? Возможно я что то делаю не так.